# Snowflake Query Tuning

Tags: sql, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below query which is taking too long to run on XS/S and errors out with an error code that recommends upgrading the WH to a higher size. We did that (M) and it ran within 10 mins. Is there any recommendation to fine-tune this query? Note, this is only a few lines from the actual query. The actual query has 20 more repetitive lines for other columns (for windows functions - `first_value(CAT) over (partition by DATE_VAL, CAM_ID, GRP_ID order by CAT nulls last) as CATEGORY)`. Based on the query profile, it spent 89% effort to evaluate/process windows functions code.

```
select * from (
        select 
                DATE_VAL, 
                CAM_ID, 
                GRP_ID,                 
                first_value(CAT) over (partition by DATE_VAL, CAM_ID, GRP_ID order by CAT nulls last) as CATEGORY,                 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by DATE_VAL, CAM_ID, GRP_ID order by TRCK nulls last ) as rnk
                from (
                select distinct
                    REPLACE(DATE, '-', '') as DATE_VAL, 
                    CAM_ID, 
                    GRP_ID, 
                    TRCK,
                    case when D.CAT = 'T' then NULL else D.CAT end as CAT,          
                from DB.SCHEMA.TAB D )
                ) where  rnk = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps remove some of the window functions? Why didn't you post the whole SQL? It seems like you've just posted a random bit of it.

Comment: Like I said, the code is exactly same with windows functions running for 20 other columns.

Comment: Let ask it this way: do you have any performance issues when you run this snippet of code by itself?

Comment: @hiphop maybe provide sample data and desired output , maybe we can rewrite it in another way.

Comment: @simonD To clarify, this piece of code runs in few seconds. It's only when I add those 20 additional lines of windows functions, it slows down.

Comment: @eshirvana The reason we replaced value of T with NULL is that we don't want it in the final result. Which is why you see we change it to null and then use nulls last so that specific rows gets filtered out by first_value

Comment: @hiphop then provide the whole code

Answer (score 1):

for starter , If I got it right , you can simplify the above query to this :

```
select
    REPLACE(DATE, '-', ''),
    CAM_ID,
    GRP_ID,
    first_value(NULLIF(D.CAT, 'T')) over (partition by DATE_VAL, CAM_ID, GRP_ID order by NULLIF(D.CAT, 'T') nulls last) as CATEGORY
from DB.SCHEMA.TAB D
qualify DENSE_RANK() over (partition by DATE_VAL, CAM_ID, GRP_ID order by TRCK nulls last) = 1
```